# Truncated normal mean and CDF

Tags: normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

Suppose $F(x;\mu,\sigma^2,0,1)$ is the CDF of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable $x$ truncated on the unit interval $(0,1)$. I'd like to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} F(x;\mu,\sigma^2,0,1)  < 0$ for any specific $x \in (0,1)$. I can empirically see this to be true but have difficulty analytically prove it.

To see an analogy, consider the (un-truncated) normal CDF $\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$. It is well known that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})=-\phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})/\sigma <0$ for any $x\in R$, as $\sigma>0$ and $\phi(x)>0$ for all $x$. I was trying to extend the result in the un-truncated normal to truncated normal on the unit interval.

Comment: A CDF is, by definition, a *function.*  Please, then, tell us what you mean by differentiating a *function* with respect to a parameter and how you manage to obtain a result that can be compared to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the question, whuber. I am treating $F$ as a function of $\mu$ with $x$ fixed. As such I can talk about partial derivative of $F$ with respect to one of its arguments. To see an analogy, consider the (un-truncated) normal CDF $G(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$. It is well known that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} G(x;\mu,\sigma^2) <0$ for any $x\in R$. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I understand the analogy and suspected you might have intended something like this, but there were plenty of other possible interpretations, too.  BTW, $G$ does not have to be Normal for this result to hold: it can be *any* location family of continuous distributions of everywhere positive density.

Comment: Agree on your point on $G$. The question is whether this result holds for truncated normal CDF on the unit interval...

Comment: It does hold.  In fact, the interval itself doesn't matter (because a change of the interval can always be brought back to the unit interval by means of a suitable change in $\mu,\sigma$).